# Is it possible to use interpolation for detached rulesets in LESS?

Tags: css, less

Suppose I have a ruleset like this:

```
@h1-ruleset: {
    font-family: @raleway;
    font-weight: @raleway-light;
};
```

I'd like to create a mixin, something like this:

```
.md-font(@ts) {
    @rs: ~"@{ts}-ruleset()";

    &--@{ts} {
        @rs; // or @@rs or @rs()
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
.md-font(h1);
```

My version doesn't compile - I can't find documentation (official or otherwise) and I'm scrambling about in the dark at the moment.

Is it possible? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use less lists to store properties you want:

```
@h1-ruleset: 
    font-family: @raleway;
    font-weight: @raleway-light;
```

Then you can create mixin that would print key-value pairs from the list. Function [extract](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-extract) returns the value at a specified position in a list by index.

```
.print-rules(@rules, @index) when (@index > 0) {
    @rule: extract(@rules, @index); // @rule is `font-family: @raleway`
    @rule-key: extract(@rule, 1);   // `font-family`
    @rule-value: extract(@rule, 2); // `@raleway`

    @{rule-key}: @rule-value;

    .print-rules(@rules, @index - 1);
}
```

Call this mixin where you want:

```
h1 {
  .print-rules(@h1-ruleset, length(@h1-ruleset));
}
```

Pay attention, the properties are printed in the reverse order.

Full code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/3rdthemagical/pen/yqGrYw).

---

**Updated:**

There is less function [each](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions-each) that does all the magic (v3.7.0):

> Bind the evaluation of a ruleset to each member of a list.

So the mixin that prints all rules may look like this:

```
.print-rules(@rules) {
  each(@rules, .(@v, @k, @i) {
    @{k}: @v;
  });
}
```

Rulesets can be stored in mixins not variables:

```
.h1-ruleset() {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

And usage:

```
h1 {
  .print-rules(.h1-ruleset());
}
```

Try this code at http://lesscss.org/less-preview/

Comment: This looks fantastic but I'm version limited using web essentials.

Answer (score 0):

"Detached rulesets" is just the wrong tool for what you want. You need just trivial mixins with your "interpolation prefix" as their parameter(s). E.g.:

```
.ruleset(h1) {
    font-family: @raleway;
    font-weight: @raleway-light;
}

.ruleset(h2) {
    font-family: @voodoo;
    font-weight: @voodoo-light;
}

// etc.
// .......

.md-font(@ts) {
    &--@{ts} {
        .ruleset(@ts);
    }
}

.foo {
   .md-font(h1);
}
```